No HTTP triggers found when deploying a local function to Azure / Python 3.10.4 being installed instead of 3.10.15 from the interpreter
I’m getting the No HTTP triggers found when deploying a local Azure function to Azure in VSC.  Azure consumption pay as you go plan, with the Python version set to 3.10 in configurations.
Deploy output shows installing Python 3.10.4 in Azure, but the interpreter is set to Python 3.10.15/venv.  With venv activated, running the function locally shows 3.10.15 is found and returns a local url without errors.  It’s as if Azure isn’t considering the interpreter or the path in pyenv.cfg and somehow using 3.10.4 instead, causing mismatched versions.
pyenv.cfg was initially auto loaded with a home path of /usr/bin instead of /home/gv/venv/bin from the venv environment, which I later manually changed.  Not sure which to use and why /home/gv/venv/bin didn’t load, but seems that one makes more sense.
Earlier testing runs included “Detected following platforms: python: 3.10.4 Version '3.10.4' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it”; that went away after the manual path switch to venv; still didn't match 3.10.15 though.
No issues with debugging the default function_ap.py file itself or running it attached to the local function, and running the function locally works, returning the expected message.
requirements.txt has dependencies via freeze > requirements.txt; no issues with these during the local run.
This is WSL/Ubuntu 24.04.1 using the Python Programming Model V2 without changes to the default format.  I’m using deadsnakes, update-alternatives, etc to allow installing 3.10.15 and setting it as the Ubuntu default instead of 3.12 that came with Ubuntu.  pip 24.3.1 is installed in venv.
Installed Azure modules in venv:
- azure-functions-core-tools-4
- azure-functions
- azure-storage-blob
- azure-identity
Many thanks.
deploy outputdebug local attached functionpyenv.cfgfunction_app.py filesettings.jsonlocal.settings.jsonhost.jsonrequirements.txt

Check if below solution helps @user28080736.

I have tried to deploy the function with your configuration/code provided and faced the same issue.
To resolve this, update local.settings.json as below:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}

Settings.json:
Change the value of "azureFunctions.deploySubpath" to "."
{
    "azureFunctions.deploySubpath": ".",
    "azureFunctions.scmDoBuildDuringDeployment": true,
    "azureFunctions.pythonVenv": "env",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguage": "Python",
    "azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~4",
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "azureFunctions.projectLanguageModel": 2
}

requirements.txt:
azure-core==1.32.0
azure-functions==1.21.3
azure-identity==1.19.0
azure-storage-blob==12.23.1
certifi==2024.8.30
cffi==1.17.1
charset-normalizer==3.4.0
cryptography==43.0.3
idna==3.10
isodate==0.7.2
msal==1.31.0
msal-extensions==1.2.0
portalocker==2.10.1
pycparser==2.22
PyJWt==2.9.0
requests==2.32.3
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.12.0
urllib3==2.2.3

function_app.py:
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.route(route="http_trigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )

Created a Consumption Plan function app with Python version 3.11 and deployed the function to it.
Deployment Logs:
6:31:25 PM kpyfn12: Starting deployment...
6:31:26 PM kpyfn12: Creating zip package...
6:31:26 PM kpyfn12: Adding 11 files to zip package...
// Removed few logs
6:31:43 PM kpyfn12: Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
6:31:43 PM kpyfn12: SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-kpyfn12.zip located
6:31:43 PM kpyfn12: Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
6:31:44 PM kpyfn12: Resetting all workers for kpyfn12.azurewebsites.net
6:31:44 PM kpyfn12: Deployment successful. deployer = ms-azuretools-vscode deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
6:31:57 PM kpyfn12: Syncing triggers...
6:32:01 PM kpyfn12: Querying triggers...

6:32:11 PM kpyfn12: HTTP Trigger Urls:
  http_trigger: https://kpyfn12.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger

Portal:
Able to see the deployed function in Azure.


Thanks Pravallika!  I've updated & now it starts to add 25k files to the zip package but ends after 20 minutes with a socket hang up error.  Tried adding SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT with a 600 time out value, same result.  In the meantime I'm getting used to running from the Azure CLI in Ubuntu; not fully up on that & my latest run using "func azure functionapp publish <function_name> --build local", returned a dependency error & suggestion to use --build remote; my function app doesn't support this.  It did return a Python version conflict & suggested I set to 3.10 in Azure or 3.11 locally.

Also, I ran Upload Local Settings against Application Settings in VSC and, because the following didn't load, I added them manually to Azure variables: "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing" & "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

Add Scm_do_build_during_deployment=true app setting in the function app and add functionTimeout: 00:30:00 in host.json and deploy again.
